# How to get aribtrary portion of a bitmap in Linux kernel program?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I have this code snippet from a baremetal program(here printf is for baremetal).

```
  rd_data = *(__GICD + GICD_TYPER);
  printf("--- GICD Page Status (GICD_TYPER)----------------------\n");
  printf("ITLineNumber(=SPIS/32):   %d\n", BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data, 3, 0)); 
  printf("SecurityExtn:             %d\n", BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data,10,10));
  printf("MBIS:                     %d\n", BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data,16,16));
  printf("LPIS:                     %d\n", BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data,17,17));
  printf("DVIS:                     %d\n", BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data,18,18));
  printf("IDbits:                   %d\n", BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data,23,19));
  printf("A3V:                      %d\n", BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data,24,24));
  printf("No1N:                     %d\n", BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data,25,25));
```

The macro BIT_FIELD_READER(rd_data, end_bit, start_bit) looks very convenient.
And now I wish to print the some registers of a peripheral registers in kernel code (using printk), and searched the kernel code if there is something similar(to copy-paste and just replace the macro).
In `include/linux/bitmap.h`, there is `bitmap_get_value8(map, start)` but it's only for getting 8 bit value.
And in `include/linux/bitfield.h`, I found something like `#define REG_FIELD_A  GENMASK(6, 0)`  and `a = FIELD_GET(REG_FIELD_A, reg);`. But this requires defining every field which is cumbsersome and not succinct. Isn't there any macro getting arbitrary bit fields using start and end position(or length) in Linux kernel code?

Comment: Couldn't you define a macro something like `#define BIT_FIELD_READER(_reg, _hi, _lo) FIELD_GET(GENMASK(_hi, _lo), _reg)`? A limitation of this macro is that the `_hi` and `_lo` macro-call arguments need to be compile-time constants.

Comment: @IanAbbott Ah, that's a good idea. I'm so not-creative..  I'll try that when I'm doing the experiment.

Comment: @IanAbbott that works nice! (I added the new define in include/linux/bitfiled.h and used it in init/main.c, no #include was needed, somehow included already) This will be convenient in many cases. Could you please make your comment an answer so I can select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BIT_FIELD_READER` macro described in the question could be defined using macros defined by `#include <linux/bitfield.h>` and `#include <linux/bits.h>` as follows:

```
#define BIT_FIELD_READER(_reg, _hi, _lo) FIELD_GET(GENMASK(_hi, _lo), _reg)
```

A restriction is that the `_hi` and `_lo` parameters need to be compile-time constants because the `FIELD_GET(_mask, _reg)` macro requires the `_mask` parameter to be a compile-time constant.

Similar wrappers around the `FIELD_PREP(_mask, _val)`, `FIELD_MAX(_mask)`, and `FIELD_FIT(_mask, _val)` macros may be useful:

```
#define BIT_FIELD_PREP(_val, _hi, _lo) FIELD_PREP(GENMASK(_hi, _lo), _val)
#define BIT_FIELD_MAX(_hi, _lo) FIELD_MAX(GENMASK(_hi, _lo)
#define BIT_FIELD_FIT(_val, _hi, _lo) FIELD_FIT(GENMASK(_hi, _lo), _val)
```

They have the same restriction that the `_hi` and `_lo` parameters need to be compile-time constants.

Comment: Yes, and we can add those definitions and use them during the debug!

Comment: Side note: There are small-letter functions for the non-constant masks are available as well.